# What is the principle of tellp() calculating the length of stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I think the length of`stringstream` is calculating by the blocks.that means how many blocks in it, how long it is.the blocks is splited by `'\t' '\s' '\n'`.

for example, `stringstream =  '23\t45\t5.677\t'` , its length should be 6. The delimiter should be counted.

I just can verify my idea while the type of arguments are all `int`.
here is my code.

I wonder that **s_double.tellp() is not 10**.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   stringstream s_int;
   stringstream s_double;
   srand((unsinged)time(NULL));

   for(int index = 0;index<5;index++)
   {
        double random = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX * 5;
        s_int<<index<<'\t';
        s_double<<random<<'\t';   
   }

   cout<<s_int.tellp()<<'\n';
   cout<<s_double.tellp()<<'\n';

   exit(0);
}
```

output:

```
10
40
```

after I changed the **range** of random, the output of **s_double** changed too.

```
double  random = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX *9;
```

output:

```
10
42
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You are using `index` at one place, and `random` at another place and expect the lengths to be same?

Comment: Try adding: `cout << s_double.str() << '\n';` to print the contents of `s_double`.

Comment: @Ajay I just want to create 5 numbers, one `int` array. one `double` array. both of them have the same length 5. After input these 5 `int` numbers and 5 `double` numbers into `stringstream`, to see the **length changed** about stringstream.  **As my excepted, the length of them must all be 10**. because I think I just input 10 strings input the `stringstream`, 5 `int` / `double` stream and 5 '\t' .

Comment: No. They won't be same.  Value in `random` would be a `double` not `int`. I am voting for closure.

Comment: @Galik Yeah, `cout<< s_double.str()<< '\n';` output the right content of what I am just inputting. Just as I understand, the `tellp()` will calculate the number of block in it. one `int` / `double` / `float` is one block, one char e.g. `\t` `\s` is also a block. so I have put 10 block in it. and the length of `stringstream` is 10.That is what I think.

Comment: Where'd you get your idea that *"tellp() will calculate the number of blocks"*?  That's just wrong.  See [`tellp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp) for docs and example with outputs (summarily: it's a count of *characters*).  If you *want* to get a count of "blocks" as you say you expect `tellp()` to have returned, that's a separate question - and not particularly hard, but also a bit strange - do you really want to count whitespace separator sequences?  What if there are two tabs in a row?  You should define any new question carefully with a few examples....

Comment: @TonyD Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest but not faster method is:

```
auto nLength = strm.str().length();
```

Regarding `s_double` position - it is easy to answer your question by examining the content of this stream in a debugger or print it. You will see that double could be "0.554213" for `0.554212545` or "1" for `1` so string length for defferent `doubles` is complitely different.